# Find total no of items in a cell?

Tags: sql-server

How can I find out total number of items in a particular cell?

In a table like:

```
eno   ename
1      hari,giri,sathish
2      naresh,suresh
3      sathish
```

I want an output like this:

```
eno    ename
1       3
2       2
3       1
```

How can it achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this trick

```
select eno,
       1 + len(ename) - len(replace(ename, ',', '')) as ename
. . .
```

That is, count the number of commas and add 1.  You can count the number of commas by taking the length of the string and subtracting the length without commas.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
Select len(ename) - len(replace(ename, ',', ''))+1 as Employee
From Table name
```

**[DEMO SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30315/7)**